# Function pointer issue: How to provide pointer from non member function to member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

i need to do something like this ..., in a project of mine.

```
class Alpha{
    
public:
    Alpha(void* p(int, int) = nullptr);
        
    void* calculatePointer;
    
    void test();
};
    

Alpha::Alpha(void* p(int, int)) : calculatePointer(p){};

Alpha::test(){
        calculatePointer(5, 10);
    }  


  
    
void calculate(int a, int b){
    std::cout << "cum: " << a +b << "\n";  
}
    
    
int main(){
    
    Alpha A = Alpha(&calculate);
    A.test();
    
}
```

and it results in in these errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(int, int)’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
       15 |     : calculatePointer(p),
          |                        ^
          |                        |
          |                        void* (*)(int, int)
error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'void *(*)(int, int)'
     error: expression cannot be used as a function
     In constructor 'Alpha::Alpha(void* (*)(int, int))':
    error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int, int)' to 'void* (*)(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
note: initializing argument 1 of 'Alpha::Alpha(void* (*)(int, int))'
```

this is just a dummy, but that's what i gotta do.
how is it done correctly?

Comment: calculatePointer is a void*, that's not a function, how do you want to store a function pointer into that without a cast ? And don't cast as it's UB, so change your type

Comment: ha, that's what I'm asking, the correct syntax.

Comment: `CalculatePointer` has type `void *`.   That is not a function pointer.   Change its type to `void (*)(int, int)` which is a pointer to a function that accepts two `int` and returns a `void`.   Also, change the type of the argument `p` in the constructor, as that specifies the argument is a pointer to a function that returns a `void *` (whereas the passed function returns `void`).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. in my project i have class, that want to access as drawing function that resides just above "int main(){...};"

Comment: Do not try to get a pointer to a function to work inside a class, before you get it to work on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're confused about the exact syntax of a function pointer it's probably best to define a type alias.

If you use `using`, the "rhs" is `<return type> (*)(<parameter types>)`

```
class Alpha{
    
public:
    using FunctionPtr = void (*)(int, int);

    Alpha(FunctionPtr p = nullptr) : calculatePointer(p) {}
        
    FunctionPtr calculatePointer;
    
    void test()
    {
        if (calculatePointer != nullptr)
        {
            calculatePointer(5, 10);
        }
    }
};
    
void calculate(int a, int b){
    std::cout << "sum: " << (a + b) << "\n";  
}
```

Btw: the correct syntax without a type alias would be

```
Alpha(void (*p)(int, int) = nullptr);
```

the brackets are necessary, since the compiler treats `void *p(int, int)` as `(void*) p(int, int)`.

Comment: indeed, it doesn't compile if you don't: (*p), but it compiles now.